# How to reference dynamic self type in interface

Tags: typescript

I need an interface that defines a class constructor and a key of the given constructor

This is what I tried, but looks like `this['cstr']` in my interface is not resolved with given constructor but rather with unknown.

```
class Foo {
  bar?: string;
}

interface IClassDescriptor {
  cstr: new () => unknown;
  key: keyof InstanceType<this['cstr']>;
}

const a: IClassDescriptor = {
  cstr: Foo,
  key: 'bar'                    // <- should be correct, but typescript emits error
};

const b: IClassDescriptor = {
  cstr: Foo,
  key: 'baz'                    // <- error, correct
};
```

Is there a way / workaorund to achieve desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Self referencing types are generally not possible in TypeScript unless you use generics. But generics require you to explictly provide a type parameter when using them as a type.

You could use a function to do the inference for you.

```
interface IClassDescriptor<T> {
  cstr: new () => T;
  key: keyof T
}

function createClassDescriptor<T>(arg: IClassDescriptor<T>) {
    return arg
}

const a = createClassDescriptor({
  cstr: Foo,
  key: 'bar'
})

const b = createClassDescriptor({
  cstr: Foo,
  key: 'baz' // Type '"baz"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'
})
```

Or specify the generic type when using `IClassDescriptor`.

```
const a: IClassDescriptor<Foo> = {
  cstr: Foo,
  key: 'bar'                  
};

const b: IClassDescriptor<Foo> = {
  cstr: Foo,
  key: 'baz' // Type '"baz"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBiB7RsDexawEYQE4H4AuWKAF1wEsA7AcwG5gBfYF60gU1wDMIR3YAkgGFIMACLsoISgAdSiXAB4AKgD40GWCDK5iVdgHdYACgCUsALzrlDTAGt2AT2IPHiLrGVMWXAK5UQUgpEKi1cdggOEWgoCSlZeSU1YzwaYmFRWMlpCjkFFVVzdExMcNJfXFDU71BwyPZo8WyEhWNirR1iJEQAGk1XYgByHFxBplMWaQiozLicvNw2zW1yLuQ++ychnAAvQdgAegPPRxl+QYAiXYv9ijgqRFJYGIoaKggsMH55WFJT86ueBu4xYoBCZGe6UaWXiuUSim66gsGkwK10CHW-S2sGGeH2JQJhMJTAYYKoEKwUNmzTh+URlhRHVWGN6WOcON2+yOJzOOMBOxusDusAeTxebw+X1+KD+vMuI2BjAYQA)

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention that I know about generics - looking for solution without generics if possible. Using function for type inference is nice idea / workaround though.
Basically the question is, why `this`  type in the interface context doesn't behave as expected...

Comment: As I said, its impossible to reference other fields in an interface. That's why `this` does not work.

Comment: Well, that's not true. With `this['cstr']` one can cleary reference the type of cstr field in interface. The problem is, that the reference is resolved to the `new () => unknown` which is written in inteface definition and not to actual type that is assigned to interface

Comment: Yes you can reference the type. But this will not help you when you are actually assigning a value. The only way to do this without generics requires all possible classes to be known beforehand. Then you could construct a union of all combinations.